# laravel session management in subdomain

Tags: laravel, session, laravel-5.1, session-management

I am struggling to manage session between domain and sub-domain 
my domain is example.com  having own laravel(5.1) folder structure and other  sub-domain having its own laravel(5.1) folder structure

domain and sub-domain access same database

```
below domain look like

example.com
forum.example.com
access same database "mydatabase"
```

session management occured only on example.com have numbers of user. I would like to access users same session in forum.example.com

Comment: What's in your `domain` array in the session.php file ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen 'domain' => '.example.com',

Answer (score 0):

To share session between your domain and sub domains you should:

1. Set the same value for domain in `app/config/session.php` as: .example.com
2. Make sure both of your Laravel applications share the same session storage, for ex. you better be using database or redis session driver
3. Make sure you have the same `APP_KEY` set in your .env file